# Placing a Navigation Div on top of bxSlider

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to place a navigation div layer on top of a bxslider. I've done the usual trick of margin-top with a minus value and z-index:9999 to keep the navigation on top of the slider, but it still disappears underneath the slider. Is there any way to place it over the top?

Here's my existing CSS code:

```
    .navigation {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:26px;
    margin-top:-75px;
    z-index:9999;
}
.navigationTab {
    background-color:#efefef;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    display:inline-block;   
    padding-left:3px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#212121;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height:31px;
    line-height:31px;
    z-index:9999;
}

.navigationTabRight {
    background:url(images/tabRight.png) no-repeat bottom;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-left:-5px;   
    height:26px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="images/HomeBanners/1.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/HomeBanners/2.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navigationTab">Home</div> <div class="navigationTabRight">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `z-index` without the element being positioned (other than the default, static) so just add `position: relative;` to enable z-index and you should see the expected results. Right now none of your elements are positioned so z-index will not work.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;   
} 

.navigation {
    position: relative;   
    width:100%;
    margin-left:26px;
    margin-top:-75px;
    z-index:9999;
}

.navigationTab {
    background-color:#efefef;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    display:inline-block;   
    padding-left:3px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#212121;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height:31px;
    line-height:31px;
    z-index:9999;
}


.navigationTabRight {
    background:url(images/tabRight.png) no-repeat bottom;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-left:-5px;   
    height:26px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Good practice is use `<li>` or `<nav>` tag to create menu or navigation. Demo of working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/B3jZ5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Setting the z-index for all elements within the navigation will fix it

```
.navigation * {
    z-index:9999;
}
```